# How to use TeaVM debugger in Intellij IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, teavm

I'm running Intellij IDEA (2018.2.4) with the TeaVM plugin (0.5.1). If I create a debug configuration for "TeaVM debug server" and debug my project I see the stop button (implying it's connected), but there are not messages in the console and the debugger tab says "detached". I haven't been able to find any documentation. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, TeaVM plugin does not print browser's console to IDEA console (I can fix this behaviour). As for detached state: did you read the [documentation](http://teavm.org/docs/tooling/debugging.html)? After you start debug configuration in IDEA, you should connect to IDEA from Chrome by pressing 'TeaVM debugger agent' button (green teapot) near the address bar.